# select data in pandas dataframe based on column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a pandas dataframe df1 and array of values a1

```
df1
col1 |col2 
A    |123
B    |321
C    |2323
D    |3232

a1
[A,B,A,D]
```

I'd like to return a dataframe df2 with len(a1) rows.

```
df2
    col1 |col2 
    A    |123
    B    |321
    A    |123
    D    |3232
```

I've been trying using iloc, loc but I can't find a suitable solution...

edit:
I've tried using

```
len(df1[df1['col1'].isin(a1)])
```

but I think this solution only returns unique rows and it doesnt duplicate them like I need it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **`set_index`** before you can use **`loc`** with your list of values:

```
a1 = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'D']
df.set_index('col1').loc[a1]

      col2
col1
A      123
B      321
A      123
D     3232
```

Comment: it works! I'm not exactly sure how set_index works, but it works.... I found a solution using isin but that one doesnt include duplicated rows. Thanks!